# filter an object by its keys based on given values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to isolate accepted value from an object based on given values `acceptedValues = ["250", "300"]` so the result should be two different arrays `arrAcceptedValues`, `notArrAcceptedValues`  i think I still missing the logic in finding the unmatched values!
I hope someone can explain it

```js
const acceptedValues = ["250", "300"];

const myObj = {
  250: [1222, 1330, 1334, 1336, 6130, 6154, 6186, 6311, 6314],
  300: [1112, 1146, 1186, 1224, 6657],
  315: [710, 717],
  545: [4778],
  700: [637, 969, 1321, 6534, 1324, 6898, 738, 6899],
  750: [6323],
  900: [1717, 1718, 1720],
  1500: [5824, 5830, 5831, 5835, 5919, 5920, 5989],
};

let arrAcceptedValues = [];
let notArrAcceptedValues = [];
for (let iterator of acceptedValues) {
  // find all values that IS contains in the myObj array ["250", "300"]
  if (myObj[iterator]) {
    const returnData = myObj[iterator];
    arrAcceptedValues.push(returnData);
  }
  // find all values that NOT contains in the myObj array ["250", "300"]
  for (const keyIterator of Object.keys(myObj)) {
    if (keyIterator !== iterator) {
      notArrAcceptedValues.push(Object.values(myObj));
    }
  }
}
console.log("arrAcceptedValues", arrAcceptedValues);
console.log("notArrAcceptedValues", notArrAcceptedValues);
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve the resuls using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

You can even make a one liner also as:

```
Object.keys(myObj).forEach((k) =>(acceptedValues.includes(k) ? arrAcceptedValues : notArrAcceptedValues).push(myObj[k]));
```

```js
const acceptedValues = ["250", "300"];

const myObj = {
  250: [1222, 1330, 1334, 1336, 6130, 6154, 6186, 6311, 6314],
  300: [1112, 1146, 1186, 1224, 6657],
  315: [710, 717],
  545: [4778],
  700: [637, 969, 1321, 6534, 1324, 6898, 738, 6899],
  750: [6323],
  900: [1717, 1718, 1720],
  1500: [5824, 5830, 5831, 5835, 5919, 5920, 5989],
};

let arrAcceptedValues = [];
let notArrAcceptedValues = [];

Object.keys(myObj).forEach((k) => {
  acceptedValues.includes(k)
    ? arrAcceptedValues.push(myObj[k])
    : notArrAcceptedValues.push(myObj[k]);
});

console.log(arrAcceptedValues);
console.log(notArrAcceptedValues);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

or

```js
const acceptedValues = ["250", "300"];

const myObj = {
  250: [1222, 1330, 1334, 1336, 6130, 6154, 6186, 6311, 6314],
  300: [1112, 1146, 1186, 1224, 6657],
  315: [710, 717],
  545: [4778],
  700: [637, 969, 1321, 6534, 1324, 6898, 738, 6899],
  750: [6323],
  900: [1717, 1718, 1720],
  1500: [5824, 5830, 5831, 5835, 5919, 5920, 5989],
};

let arrAcceptedValues = [];
let notArrAcceptedValues = [];

Object.keys(myObj).forEach((k) =>(acceptedValues.includes(k) ? arrAcceptedValues : notArrAcceptedValues).push(myObj[k]));

console.log(arrAcceptedValues);
console.log(notArrAcceptedValues);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Very good solution. I would have done it with map and used const instead of let. used your code below in my answer and adapted it. good tip with the css of the console. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: thank you it's really great, but I was trying to push the whole obj instead of only the value, but it's pushing all of it and ignoring the filter `arrAcceptedValues.push(myObj) `  !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Code:

```js
const myObj = {
  250: [1222, 1330, 1334, 1336, 6130, 6154, 6186, 6311, 6314],
  300: [1112, 1146, 1186, 1224, 6657],
  315: [710, 717],
  545: [4778],
  700: [637, 969, 1321, 6534, 1324, 6898, 738, 6899],
  750: [6323],
  900: [1717, 1718, 1720],
  1500: [5824, 5830, 5831, 5835, 5919, 5920, 5989],
}

const acceptedValues = ['250', '300']

const result = Object.entries(myObj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  (acceptedValues.includes(k) ? a.arrAcceptedValues : a.notArrAcceptedValues).push(v)
  return a
}, { arrAcceptedValues: [], notArrAcceptedValues: [] })

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the decpk answer, here is the solution with map.

```js
const acceptedValues = ["250", "300"];

const myObj = {
  250: [1222, 1330, 1334, 1336, 6130, 6154, 6186, 6311, 6314],
  300: [1112, 1146, 1186, 1224, 6657],
  315: [710, 717],
  545: [4778],
  700: [637, 969, 1321, 6534, 1324, 6898, 738, 6899],
  750: [6323],
  900: [1717, 1718, 1720],
  1500: [5824, 5830, 5831, 5835, 5919, 5920, 5989],
};

const arrAcceptedValues = [];
const notArrAcceptedValues = [];

Object.keys(myObj).map((key) => {
  (acceptedValues.includes(key) ? arrAcceptedValues : notArrAcceptedValues).push(myObj[key])
})

console.log(arrAcceptedValues);
console.log(notArrAcceptedValues);
```

Comment: If you are not using the returned value of `map`, then no need to use `Map` use forEach instead.

Comment: @decpk You are right. and for this case it is perfectly sufficient. for larger arithmetic operations or larger data sets, map is simply more perfomanent.  then I would go for map, because the fact that map creates a new array is not a problem.